# Excel don't recognize formulas from closedXML / c#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, formulas, closedxml

> Info: The following code is in a foreach loop

**Works:**

```
indexSheet.Cell("G" + cellIndex).FormulaA1 = "=SUM(A1:A10)";
```

**Only works, when i type this directly in excel:**

```
indexSheet.Cell("G" + cellIndex).FormulaA1 = "=FIND(\"erw\";H5)"; // with Property
indexSheet.Cell("G" + cellIndex).SetFormulaA1("=FIND(\"erw\";H5)");  //with Function
indexSheet.Cell("G" + cellIndex).FormulaA1 = $"COUNTIF(H{cellIndex};\"*\"&$C$2&\"*\")*(MAX($G$4:G{cellIndex - 1})+1)";
indexSheet.Cell("B" + cellIndex).FormulaA1 = $"=IF(ROW()-{cellIndex}>MAX(G:G);\"\";HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(\"#\";(INDEX(H:H;MATCH(ROW()-4;G:G;0)));\"!B{cellIndex}\");(INDEX(H:H;MATCH(ROW()-4;G:G;0)))))";
```

**I've checked/tried:**

1. Because in stackoverflow exists a similar case: If the language of my functions matching with my excel language (both are english)
2. I tried if simpler formulas would work like `SUM()` or `FIND()` --> (-SUM works, FIND doesn't work )
3. I typed the formulas directly in an excelsheet (formulas working here)
4. I tried it outside from the Loop with a hard-coded cell-informations and without the "cellindex"-variable
5. Checked out the closedXML-documentation
6. Whit equal signs at the beginning of the formulas and without it
7. I tried with closedXML Vers. 0.76.0 and 0.80.1 (latest stable)

**Excel shows me this:**
[Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqLQF.png)

**And this:** 
[Picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c4d3.png)

**The Linked XML-logfile from Picture 2 contains informations about the deleted parts**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <logFileName>error035720_03.xml</logFileName><summary>Errors were detected in file 'C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Output\CodeBook.xlsx'</summary>
    <removedRecords>
        <removedRecord>Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet.xml part</removedRecord>
        <removedRecord>Removed Records: Formula from /xl/calcChain.xml part (Calculation properties)</removedRecord>
    </removedRecords>
</recoveryLog>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can't use semicolon (`;`) to separate arguments in closedxml. Use comma(`,`) like this:

```
indexSheet.Cell("G" + cellIndex).FormulaA1 = "=FIND(\"erw\",H5)";
```

that is the reason why `SUM(range)` works but `FIND(find_text;within_text)` does not...

Answer (score 1):

You must using comma(,) to separate argunments. Dont use semicolon (;) like excel

Comment: This answer is no different from the accepted one - I recommend to delete it.